# file handling + word scraping (trying to find all the words in a file that end with 'y')

Tags: python, web-scraping, file-handling, pdf-scraping

ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\Pranjal\Desktop\tstp\zen_scraper.py", line 5, in words = re.findall("$y",file) File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object PS C:\Users\Pranjal\Desktop\tstp>

```
import re

file = open("zen.txt",'r')

words = re.findall("$y",file)
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have opened the file but you haven't got its content yet.
Also, `re` is not necessary here, `str.endswith()` is all you need.

```
with open("zen.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            if word.endswith('y'):
                print(word)
```

Comment: how does python recognise "line" and "word" ????are these python in built keywords???@alec_djinn

Comment: @PranjalRuhela no, any variable name would do. f is a file object that you can think of it as a list of lines. So iterating over it give you the lines. Each line is a string made by words separated by spaces, .split() makes a list of words out of it. Check this https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-files